# Why when i convert type it also print?

Tags: python, list, numpy

why when write this line:

```
lines = float(lines)
```

or this line:

```
lines = np.array(''.join(lines), dtype = float)
```

and i run the code (*F5 in IDLE*) it also print out the data?

```
FYI - lines =  ['.0 .0 .3 .7 .2 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 ', '.0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 ']
```

list of strings, thank you.

Comment: Please add the code definition for variable 'lines' too. Just what does 'lines' contain. That would be helpful.

Comment: i added it in the : "FYI"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be printing out the data as part of an error. I am unable to get your code to run as currently specified, and I get the following error which also prints out the data:

```
lines = ['.0 .0 .3 .7 .2 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 ', '.0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 ']
lines = np.array(''.join(lines), dtype = float)
```

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.0 .0 .3 .7 .2 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 .0 '
```